# Image in Cardview has margin on right side

Tags: android-layout

I have an image in the top of a card view. It has a litte (unwanted) margin one the right and I don't know why... Maybe someone can give me a hint how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

If i don't use "adjustViewBounds", it works. But I need it for further views under the image.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/nature"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/exercise_picture"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: instead of xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" use xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the ImageView scaleType to something that fills all the provided space such as cropCenter.

fitStart will fit the whole image into the space and preserve the aspect ratio. Since the image is a bit taller than the CardView and you set it to fitStart, there may be some extra space on the right.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/nature"
    android:scaleType="cropCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/exercise_picture"/>
```